# Mongoosejs validation undefined property

Tags: mongoose

If I've got a rule like:

```
CommentSchema.path('body').validate(function(body) {
    return body.length;
}, 'Body cannot be empty');
```

if I do for instance:

```
curl -d "author=Kris" \
-d "email=Jordan" \
http://localhost:3000/api/comment
```

the server crash with an error message like:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

so I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid all the times
in every rules) doing :

```
CommentSchema.path('body').validate(function(body) {
    if(typeof body !== "undefined" && body !== null){
        return body.length > 0
    }
    return false;
}, 'Body cannot be empty');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simplify it to:

```js
CommentSchema.path('body').validate(function(body) {
    return !!body;
}, 'Body cannot be empty');
```

The `!!` isn't strictly necessary, but it helps clarify what's going on by explicitly evaluating `body` as a boolean.  `null`, `undefined`, and `''` all evaluate to false.

Comment: `body && body.length` is another alternative.